# AmazonSimpleEmailService Send mail to Addresses with German umlaut characters like 'ü'

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, email, encoding, amazon-ses

I'm Using AmazonSimpleEmailService in my poject , it's works like a charm
but when i try to send mails to addresses with German umlaut characters like 'hüttem@byom.de' , i got rejected and i have this stack Error :

```
ERROR AwsSesMailSender.sendMailWithReplyTo(AwsSesMailSender.java:79) --- ATTACHMENT FILE - ADDITIONAL TRACES TO DEBUG ---2023-04-06 11:39:45.978 ERROR AwsSesMailSender.sendMailWithReplyTo(AwsSesMailSender.java:80) --- ATTACHMENT FILE -  com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceException: Local address contains control or whitespace (Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 5f2e93e2-d471-463f-8bb3-78cea907abf1)at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1711)at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1366)at
```

i tried IDN.toAscii () and also tried to change encoding

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I wonder whether it would work if you send to `huttem@byom.de`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Nop we don't receive the email if i replace hüttem@byom.de with huttem@byom.de , but i don't get the error stack